# Starting on a new line doesn't work after adding hyperlink

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink

I've added a hyperlink to my layout, which is full of text. In my `xml` file, I have a lot of text with a link in it. Everytime I want to start on a new line, I add \n or \n\n to it, which used to work. Now that I added the hyperlink in my XML using `<a href='https://www.rkz.nl'> </a>`, the enters are gone. Everything is placed after everything, leaving no open lines or spaces.

This is how it looks in the emulator:
[image]

this is my `xml` code with text:

```
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_contact">    Contact\n\nTelefoon en internet Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis\nT 0251 26 5555 (algemeen nummer, ook Poli IJmuiden)\nwww.rkz.nl<a href='https://www.rkz.nl'> </a>\n\nHuisartsenpost Midden-Kennemerland (begane grond RKZ)\nVoor huisartsenzorg buiten kantooruren\nT 0251 26 5265\n
    (A.u.b. bellen voordat u langskomt)\n Spoedeisende Hulp RKZ en Huisartsenpost: meer informatie\nBij levensbedreigende klachten belt u altijd 112\n\nBezoek- en postadres Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis\nVondellaan 13\n1942 LE Beverwijk\nRoute(link)\nPostbus 1074\n1940 EB Beverwijk
</string>
```

If you need my Main or layout activity code, please ask so. Hope someone has some answers for this.

Comment: Try with `&lt;br /&gt;`

Comment: you mean &lt;br /&gt; every time instead of \n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `\n` try to use `&lt;br /&gt` it will act as a `</br>` in `html`

### Example

```
 <string name="new_line">New&lt;br /&gt;Line</string>
```

By the way the best way to add `html` in `strings.xml` you should use `CDATA`

```
![CDATA[CODE_HTML]]>
```

### Example

```
<string name="some_html">![CDATA[<p>Some_Text<p>]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class from Android SDK.

`Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);`

It will scan the text and add clickable links to web URL.